# How to save a video using OpenCV VideoWriter to a specific directory -- python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, video, video-processing

I am trying to save a video in a specific folder.
but after running the code no output is saved.
Could anyone help? Thanks.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_paths[0])
fgbg = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
name = "C:\jupyter_projects\Test Folder\Intention dataset\background_subtracted\out.mp4"
out = cv2.VideoWriter(name,fourcc, 20,(320,180),False)

while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if (ret == True):
        resized_frame = cv2.resize(frame,(320,180),fx=0,fy=0, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        fgmask = fgbg.apply(resized_frame)
        cv2.imshow('Frame',fgmask)
        out.write(fgmask)
        if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.waitKey(5)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

PS: when I use default directory for saving videos output will be saved.

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter("out.mp4",fourcc, 20,(320,180),False)
```

Comment: I guess you have to escape those spaces in the path. In windows for example: "\"C:/Videos/Otters are the cutest/VerySweetOtter.mp4\""

Comment: @Tollpatsch I've changed my path but not worked again. only default path is working for that

Comment: Have you tried using forward slash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call the function

```
cv2.VideoWriter("/your/path/filename.mp4",fourcc, 20,(320,180))
```

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```py
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')
```

instead of

```py
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
```

Comment: not worked, the problem is about changing directory. when I use default directory output will be saved.

Answer (score 1):

### Using [`createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d7b/classcv_1_1BackgroundSubtractorMOG2.html),

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# fgbg = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
name = "C://path//of//your_dir//out.mp4"
out = cv2.VideoWriter(name,fourcc, 20,(320,180),False)

while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if (ret == True):
        resized_frame = cv2.resize(frame,(320,180),fx=0,fy=0, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        fgmask = fgbg.apply(resized_frame)
        cv2.imshow('Frame',fgmask)
        out.write(fgmask)
        if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.waitKey(5)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This will save your out.mp4 given location. You can also use single forward slash instead of double forward slash, when specifying location of your file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quote and using double slash for your file directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, use a raw string in the format of: r"C:\bluh bluh directory\abc"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).